# Set an Active property to only 1 model in a Backbone Collection at any time

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a collection of Backbone models.  I want to set a model property to 'active' but make sure that only 1 model can be active at a time.  I have not been able to get this to work and am looking for some guidance.

Here is a fiddle to my code:  http://jsfiddle.net/doen1mm9/

Here is my JavaScript and Templates.

JS:

```
var data = [
    {
        "color": "blue",
        "name": "Johnny"
    },
    {
        "color": "green",
        "name": "Melissa"
    },
    {
        "color": "yellow",
        "name": "Bill"
    }
];

var TheModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
});

var TheCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TheModel,

    initialize: function() {
        this.on('change:isActive', this.ensureSingleActive, this);
    },

    ensureSingleActive: function(current) {
        var previous = this.findWhere({isActive: true});

        if (previous !== undefined) {
            previous.set('isActive', false);   
        }

        current.set('isActive', true);
    }
});

var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.js-container',

    tagName: 'ul',

    render: function() {
        this.collection.each(function(item) {
            var listItemView = new ListItemView({model: item});
            this.$el.append(listItemView.el);
        }, this);
    } 
});

var ListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
        this.render();
    },

    tagName: 'li',

    template: _.template( $('#item-template').html() ),

    render: function() {
        var temp = this.template({model: this.model.toJSON()});

        this.$el.html( temp );
    },

    events: {
        'click': 'toggleActive'   
    },

    toggleActive: function(e) {
        this.model.set('isActive');
        console.log(this.model.toJSON());
    }
});

var theCollection = new TheCollection(data);

var listView = new ListView({collection: theCollection});
listView.render();
```

Template:

```
<div class="js-container"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
    <span <% if (model.isActive === true) { %> class="active" <% } %>>
        <%- model.name %>
    </span>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/ManikandanK/c477rone/1/
There are two things you need to correct.

```
ensureSingleActive: function(current) {
    if(current.get('isActive') ) {

        var previous=   _.find(this.models, function(model) {
            return model != current && model.get('isActive') 
        });

    if (previous) {
        previous.set('isActive', false);   
    } 
}
}
```

When you are inside this function, already current model value is already set. so you dont need to set the value again. You missed to pass the value to set function.

```
this.model.set('isActive', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on other answers, you could sidestep events and just call a method on your collection directly.

In your view:

```
activate: function() {
  this.model.collection.setActive(this.model)
}
```

And then in your collection:

```
setActive: function(model) {
  this.each( function(m) { m.set('selected', m === model) }
}
```

Readable, slightly less performant, but shouldn't matter unless you're working with massive collections.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the extra parameter here:

```
toggleActive: function(e) {
        this.model.set('isActive'); // this.model.set('isActive', true);
```

Even if you fix this though, the example you got won't work because you will stuck in an infinite loop.

```
this.on('change:isActive', this.ensureSingleActive, this);
```

'ensureSingleActive' will get called each time isActive is change and thus it will get repeatedly called as you set isActive within there for other models.

What I suggest is to ensure that the only one will be active at a time within your ListView. Trigger a custom even from the ListItemView and ensure that that only one is selected.

I hope that his helps.

Comment: I did notice that I was getting an infinite loop in some of my attempts.  Thank you for the advice! I was thinking it would be a good idea to use the model as a way to set the active item rather than searching the list for a class, removing it, and adding the class to the clicked item.

Comment: Well once the model its set, its data changes and based on your code it will render. To me it seems a bit counter intuitive to do it like that. From what I can see, you need a component which has knowledge of the model to set as active, and the collection of the other ListItems... so based on that i suggested the ListView.